# Is this possible to select with keyboard tab a Span Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is this possible to select with keyboard tab a Span Object? I have applied onclick function to that span. I want to select the span along with anchor tags with keyboard tab button.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's very bad idea to do so! Better is to dynamically add anchor element styled like a span, note that onclick should return false, to prevent browser from loading new page. Here [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/PuGwE/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$(body).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '9') { 
        //select the text
    }
});
```

As for selecting the text itself. See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse/987376#987376)**

Comment: This is my code - http://jsfiddle.net/PuGwE/     The above function is not working with my code. Can you please  look my code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using `tabindex="0"` in the span tag. Keeping `tabindex="-1"` skips the element when tab is used.

```
<span tabindex="0">Focus this element on tab</span>
```